# How to calculate Matrix exponential with Tailor series PARALLEL using MPI c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Need to calculate Matrix exponential with Tailor series with MPI matrix is small 3 x 3 for example

Meanwhile

```
vector<vector<double>> matrixMult(const vector<vector<double>>& A, const vector<vector<double>>& B) {
    int n = A.size();
    vector<vector<double>> C(n, vector<double>(n, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    return C;
}
vector<vector<double>> matrixExp(const vector<vector<double>>& A) {
    int n = A.size();
    vector<vector<double>> E(n, vector<double>(n, 0));
    vector<vector<double>> T(n, vector<double>(n, 0));
    vector<vector<double>> localE(n, vector<double>(n, 0));

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        E[i][i] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        localE[i][i] = 0;

    T = E;
    for (int j = 1; j <= rank; j++) 
    {
        T = matrixMult(T, A);
        T = matrixDiv(T, j);
    }
    localE = T;
    for (int i = rank + 1; i <= N; i += size) {
        for (int j = i; j < i + size; j++) {
            T = matrixMult(T, A);
            T = matrixDiv(T, j);
        }
        localE = matrixSum(localE, T);
    }
    MPI_Reduce(localE[0].data(), E[0].data(), n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(localE[1].data(), E[1].data(), n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(localE[2].data(), E[2].data(), n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    return E;
}
```

But i dont know how to optimize this

```
for (int j = i; j < i + size; j++) {
            T = matrixMult(T, A);
            T = matrixDiv(T, j);
        }
```

Maybe it's impossible with this implementation
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc65Z.png)

Comment: `vector<vector<double>>` is an antipattern : it is generally bad for performance. I do not understand the purpose of using MPI for a 3x3 matrix. This will be much much slower than a sequential code. Besides, please embed the image in the post rather than using a link.

Comment: it is just for example i want to know scheme to calc it parallel for cubic matrix n x n

Comment: and i cant post photo - You need at least 10 reputation to post images.  :(

Comment: I don't understand the code. The `matrixMult` call is inside an `i,j` loop, but does not actually involve `i` or `j`. Maybe you should give source of the `mult` and `div` routines?

Comment: my implementation is very bad in j loop i calc next member of the series for each process i += size means 0 proc will calc for 0 and 4 member  of the series in scheme there is a photo; mult and div is just a functions for multiply matrix and div matrix by num; i added only for multiplying matrixes